# Join point by using Tikz in Beamer document class

Tags: plot, tikz-styles

I know my question is trivial. By the way, I can not show points given by their coordinates with a Bezier curve using Tikz.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [<->,thick] (0,2) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$}
            |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
    %\draw [gray!50]  (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (3,1) -- (1,0)  -- (2,-1) -- cycle;
    \draw [red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (1.5, 1.5) (2,1.5) (2.5,2) (3,1) (1,0) (2,-1)};

    %\draw [gray!50, xshift=4cm]  (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,-2) -- (3,0);
    %\draw [cyan, xshift=4cm] plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2,-2) (3,0)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

I would like to give a draw like this

[image]

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: And, yes, you can definitely use `tikz` in `beamer`. `:)`

Comment: Just add `mark=*` after the `smooth` option. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @cmhughes: Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show plot the individual points by adding `mark=*` to the `plot` options, which will use a filled circle marker. There are many marker types, and they can be styled independently of the plot line (e.g. their size, colour, line thickness, etc.). Refer to the manual for more details.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [<->,thick] (0,2) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$}
            |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
    \draw [red] plot [smooth, mark=*] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (1.5, 1.5) (2,1.5) (2.5,2) (3,1) (1,0) (2,-1)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Averroès: Thanks for accepting! In the process, you also downvoted the answer by clicking the downward pointing triangle. I assume that was by accident? In that case, would you mind undoing the downvote?